# Root of $x\sin x-1=0$ using fixed point iteration

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-iteration

How to find the root of the equation $x\sin x-1=0$  between [2 , 3] using fixed point iteration?
I tried $x=1/\sin x$ and $x=\arcsin (1/x)$ but does not converge the root between [2 , 3].

Comment: The iteration $x = f(x)$ may not converge because $|f'(x)| > 1$ at that root. Use Aitken or Steffenson.

Comment: Why a fixed point iteration? Over the interval $[2,3]$ the given function is concave, hence Newton's method with starting point $x=3$ converges pretty fast to the only solution, $x\approx 2.7726$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arcsine always returns a value in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ so you want $x=\pi-\arcsin(1/x)$

Comment: what about find the root over the interval [0,2]?? because $x=\pi -arcsin(\frac{1}{x})$ is not well-behave 

Comment: @emonhossain:  there you can use $x=\frac 1{\sin x}$.  You want an expression on the right that has derivative less than $1$ in absolute value.

Comment: But $g(x)=\frac{1}{sin(x)}$ is not define at point $0$. What I follow to find $g(x)$ is first find such $g(x)\in[a,b]\forall x\in[a,b]$ then according to Contraction Mapping Theorem it was guaranteed that $g(x)$ has a unique ﬁxed point ξ in the interval $[a, b]$. Am I doing it in a proper way? @Ross Millikan Sir

Comment: Fixed point iteration only needs the function to be defined near the root.  Here the root is about $1.114$.  Starting at $1$ converges nicely

Comment: One last question, before knowing the root how can you guarantee that?? @Ross Millikan Sir. Because if the function is complicate to draw or guessing the root then it might be misleading us..Is it?\

Comment: It is always an advantage to be able to graph the function and get an approximate root.  Many of the root finding methods. like bisection, rely on being able to bracket the root-to find two points where the function has opposite signs.  As long as the function is continuous there must be a root in there somewhere.  Without that, the function you choose for fixed point iteration may have a slope greater than $1$ and you will run away from the root.  If fixed point converges, it is a root, but maybe not the one you want.